# CYGWIN WARNING: Couldn't comute FAST__CWD

Tags: cygwin

Hi we are currently using Quickbuild for our Automation Jobs,apparently as we tried to deploy some changes we are unable to proceed due to this: [image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried updating our git version to the latest, and I have also tried to install a cygwin latest version, none of this has solved our problem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/787) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313269/git-extensions-fetch-all-throwing-a-cygwin-warning-couldnt-compute-fast-cwd-p)?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem after I upgraded my machine to Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 25905; I received the warning message when I opened a git bash prompt or used unix tools such as diff.exe.

The solution for me was to upgrade [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) from 2.39.1 to 2.41.0.3.
I suggest you identify the tool (.exe) that outputs the warning message and see if the latest version of the tool can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-find_fast_cwd-warnings

```
4.45.

How do I fix find_fast_cwd warnings?

Older Cygwin releases asked users to report problems to the mailing list with the message:

    find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer. Please report
    this problem to the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
Recent Cygwin releases changed this to the message:

    This typically occurs if you're using an older Cygwin version on a newer Windows.
    Please update to the latest available Cygwin version from https://cygwin.com/.
    If the problem persists, please see https://cygwin.com/problems.html.
This is not serious, just a warning that Cygwin may not always be able to exactly emulate all aspects of Unix current directory handling under your Windows release.

Unfortunately some projects and products still distribute older Cygwin releases which may not fully support newer Windows releases, instead of installing the current release from the Cygwin project. They also may not provide any obvious way to keep the Cygwin packages their application uses up to date with fixes for security issues and upgrades.

The solution is simply downloading and running the Cygwin Setup program, following the instructions in the Internet Setup section of ``Setting Up Cygwin'' in the Cygwin User's Guide.

Please exit from all applications before running the Cygwin Setup program. When running Setup, you should not change most of the values presented, just select the Next button in most cases, as you already have a Cygwin release installed, and only want to upgrade your current installation. You should make your own selection if the internet connection to your system requires a proxy; and you must always pick an up to date Cygwin download (mirror) site, preferably the site nearest to your system for faster downloads, as shown, with more details to help you choose, on the Mirror Sites web page.

The Cygwin Setup program will download and apply upgrades to all packages required for Cygwin itself and installed applications. Any problems with applying updates, or the application after updates, should be reported to the project or product supplier for remedial action.

As Cygwin is a volunteer project, unable to provide support for older releases installed by projects or products, it would be helpful to let other users know what project or product you installed, in a quick email.
```